# unity C# object Instance = null

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

help me please
I'm doing an assignment and I'm having trouble with my code
I'm trying to have an instance of weaponStats that I can reference back for stats on weapons and in the gameManager it changes weaponID to the current equipped weapon on the player but when i try to hit an enemy unity says that stats is = to null

On the line "if (stats.weaponID == 1)" I receive a null reference error I've tried a number of different ways to instantiate but still get the null error

yet i don't receive an error in other classes

please see the function below

```
    public void Shoot(bool isTesting = false)
{
    Vector2 mousePosition = new Vector2(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y);
    Vector2 firePointPosition = new Vector2(firePoint.position.x, firePoint.position.y);
    Vector2 direction = mousePosition - firePointPosition;
    if (isTesting)
    {
        direction = transform.right;
    }
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(firePointPosition, direction, 100, whatToHit.value);

    // kill the enemy nothing else and check what weapon it was
    if (hit.collider != null) {
        Enemy enemy = hit.collider.GetComponent<Enemy>();
        if (enemy != null) {

            if (stats == null)
            {
                stats = WeaponStats.instance;
            }

            if (stats.weaponID == 1)
            {
                enemy.Damaged(stats._PistolDamage);
            }
            else if (stats.weaponID == 2)
            {
                enemy.Damaged(stats._RifleDamage);
            }
            else {

                Debug.Log("HELP!!");

            }

        }
    }

    // spawn effects
    if (Time.time >= timeToSpawnEffect) {
        Vector3 hitPos;
        Vector3 hitNormal;

        if (hit.collider == null) {
            hitPos = direction * 35;
            hitNormal = new Vector3(9999, 9999, 9999);
        } else {
            hitPos = hit.point;
            hitNormal = hit.normal;
        }

        Effect(hitPos, hitNormal);
        timeToSpawnEffect = Time.time + 1 / effectSpawnRate;
    }
}
```

This is a copy of the weaponstats class

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class WeaponStats : MonoBehaviour {

    public static WeaponStats instance;

    public int weaponID = 0;

    // dmage based on equiped weapon
    public float Damage = 10f;
    public float Firerate = 7.5f;

    #region Weapons

        #region Pistol
        public float _PistolDamage = 30f;
        public float _PistolFirerate = 0f;
        #endregion

        #region Rifle
        public float _RifleDamage = 10f;
        public float _RifleFirerate = 7.5f;
        #endregion

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// if weapon stats instance = to null
    /// </summary>
    void Awake() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = this;
        }
    }
}
```

In this script it works perfectly fine

```
using UnityEngine;
```

using UnityEngine.UI;

public class WeaponUpgrading : WeaponStats {

```
// weapons text fields
#region Pistol
[SerializeField]
private Text PistolDamage;

[SerializeField]
private Text PistolFirerate;
#endregion
#region Rifle
[SerializeField]
private Text RifleDamage;

[SerializeField]
private Text RifleFirerate;
#endregion

#region Modifires
[SerializeField]
private float DamageMultiplier = 1.3f;

[SerializeField]
private float FirerateMultiplier = 1.3f;
#endregion

private WeaponStats stats;

void Start() {

    stats = WeaponStats.instance;
    UpdateValues(0); // update all on load

}

void UpdateValues(int ID) {

    switch (ID) {

        case 1:
            // update pistol
            PistolDamage.text = "Damage: " + stats._PistolDamage.ToString();
            PistolFirerate.text = "Firerate: " + stats._PistolFirerate.ToString();

            break;

        case 2:
            // update rifle
            RifleDamage.text = "Damage: " + stats._RifleDamage.ToString();
            RifleFirerate.text = "Firerate: " + stats._RifleFirerate.ToString();

            break;

        default:
            // refresh all on default
            PistolDamage.text = "Damage: " + stats._PistolDamage.ToString();
            PistolFirerate.text = "Firerate: " + stats._PistolFirerate.ToString();

            RifleDamage.text = "Damage: " + stats._RifleDamage.ToString();
            RifleFirerate.text = "Firerate: " + stats._RifleFirerate.ToString();

            break;

    }  

}

public void UpgradePistol() 
    {

    //Debug.Log(s)
    /*
    stats.PistolDamage = (stats.PistolDamage * DamageMultiplier);
    stats.PistolFirerate = Mathf.Round(stats.PistolFirerate * FirerateMultiplier);

    UpdateValues(1);
    */

    stats._PistolDamage = stats._PistolDamage * DamageMultiplier;
    PistolDamage.text = "" + stats._PistolDamage;

}

public void UpgradeRifle() {


    stats._RifleDamage = stats._RifleDamage * DamageMultiplier;
    RifleDamage.text = "" + stats._RifleDamage;

    stats._RifleDamage = stats._RifleDamage * DamageMultiplier;
    RifleDamage.text = "" + stats._RifleFirerate * FirerateMultiplier;

    /*
    stats.RifleDamage = (int)(stats.RifleDamage * DamageMultiplier);
    stats.RifleFirerate = Mathf.Round(stats.RifleFirerate * FirerateMultiplier);
    */
    //UpdateValues(2);
}
```

}

Comment: `stats = WeaponStats.instance;` Basically, this exception occurs because `stats = WeaponStats.instance` is null. You need to fix that.

Comment: If you want instance of `WeaponStats` to exist, you at least need to attach `WeaponStats` to one GameObject. Just create an empty GameObject and attach `WeaponStats` to it. That's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason you still get a `NullReferenceException` for `stats = WeaponStats.instance` is because no where you actually initialize `WeaponStats.instance`. having it as a static member of the class does not initialize it.
The only place you access it is in the `Awake` method which is not being called.

It might be that it is worth having a look at the Singelton design pattern - it seems like you are trying to do something similar to it.

Look here for [dofactory.com](http://www.dofactory.com/net/singleton-design-pattern) on Singelton

Comment: in another script it works fine when i upgrade the weapon damages though so its being called i dont know why its just that script

Comment: @Razzel - might be that somewhere else it works but in the given code you do not initialize it anywhere - hence the error

Comment: i placed more code into my question because they both do the exact same thing i tried to instantiate it in the broken script but it had no effect.

i did a debug on it and it sees the variables but the stats base is null for some reason

Comment: @Razzel - added code does not help solving it. There too you use `Start` to assign a value to the variable but do not show where you actually call the `Start`. But in any case problem is that you do not initialize your variable before using it. If you initialize it through a helper function you must make sure the function is called first

Comment: OMG!!! IM AN IDIOT!!! thanks a lot man :D I was instancing nothing xDDD

Comment: I kept trying to call a reference to a thing that wasn't there